# Multiple Unexplained Error Messages using AVAudioRecorder

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiorecorder

I'm working on a project for a class (I'm learning Swift/iOS) in which I have to use AVAudioRecorder, and I am getting the following error messages in the debug panel upon running my app (though the app is building successfully):

```
2020-08-09 20:28:41.073178+0200 MyAppName[49311:2895565] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x600002409fe0> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46


2020-08-09 20:28:41.165556+0200 MyAppName[49311:2895565]  PropertyID=1667788144 is NULL


2020-08-09 20:28:47.007202+0200 MyAppName[49311:2895894] [aqme] AQMEIO_HAL.cpp:1526:IOProc: AQDefaultDevice: Abandoning I/O cycle because reconfig pending (1).
```

I've tried looking online and can't find anything to explain these error messages. Any ideas? I appreciate the feedback.

As per the request for the code for AVAudioRecorder, it's as follows:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class RecordSoundsViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioRecorderDelegate {
    
    var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var recordingLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var recordButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var stopRecordingButton: UIButton!
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        stopRecordingButton.isEnabled = false
                }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        print("viewWillAppear called")
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func recordAudio(_ sender: Any) {
        print("The 'Record' button was pressed.")
        recordingLabel.text = "Recording in Progress"
        stopRecordingButton.isEnabled = true
        recordButton.isEnabled = false
        
        let dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory,.userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
        let recordingName = "recordedVoice.wav"
        let pathArray = [dirPath, recordingName]
        let filePath = URL(string: pathArray.joined(separator: "/"))
        
        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try! session.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, mode: AVAudioSession.Mode.default, options: AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker)
        
        try! audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(url: filePath!, settings: [:])
        audioRecorder.delegate = self
        audioRecorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
        audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
        audioRecorder.record()
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func stopRecording(_ sender: Any) {
        print("The 'Stop Recording' button was pressed.")
        recordingLabel.text = "Tap to Record"
        recordButton.isEnabled = true
        stopRecordingButton.isEnabled = false
        audioRecorder.stop()
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try! audioSession.setActive(false)
        
        
    }
    
 
    func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(_ recorder: AVAudioRecorder, successfully flag: Bool) {
        print("The app has finished the recording.")
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Could you share your code of declaring and using AVAudioRecorder and other AV-related components?

Comment: Never mind the console messages. Does the recording actually work? What bad thing happens _in the app?_

Comment: The recording works (so far), however, I have to submit this project for review and I'm worried that these messages will hinder my project from getting a passing grade. I would like to rid my app of these messages if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running on a device? I believe that all of these are simulator messages only and can be ignored.