iOS simulator will not record audio
This has been an ongoing issues for me since XCode 15 I'm not able to record audio on any iOS simulators. I've attempted changing all settings I could find but nothing has worked.
Not only is the app I'm developing not able to record audio, but nothing on the device for example Siri and voice text do not work.
I tried with the simulators audio input set as the Mac, and with an external microphones still nothing works.
This error is given when initially trying to record:
AQMEIO_HAL.cpp:2791  iOSSimulatorAudioDevice-23053-2: Abandoning I/O cycle because reconfig pending (1).
This is only an issue with the Simulator, if I run on a physical device things work as expected.

Tried running on multiple iOS versions from 16.0 through 17.5
Cleared simulator and all it's data
Tried multiple different device types
Deleted XCode/ Simulator and reinstalled
Settings > Privacy & Security > Microphone : Doesn't list XCode or Simulator as an option for microphone, and there's no option to add other services


Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63330073/multiple-unexplained-error-messages-using-avaudiorecorder — The Simulator is not intended as a perfect replica of a device. Test on a device and move on. Feel free to report a bug to Apple too, but don't expect a "solution" from Stack Overflow.

@matt I have reported a bug to Apple. This is a feature that used to work on my simulators before XCode 15, and to my knowledge it's not an issue for most other people. So I'd expect there is some way to fix this/ a config I have wrong. I don't know where else to go for a solution.

Having the same issue and I don't remember Apple mentioned recording with simulator as a poor approach
